# Definition of dynamic member

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a more precise definition of **dynamic member** than the fuzzy one I currently have in my head.

I'm reading Nicolai Jossutis's book *Object-Oriented Programming in C++*.  I'm in the chapter on dynamic members of classes.  I thought I was understanding dynamic members until I got to the part of the chapter called "Classes Containing Classes" (6.4 in my book, page 406 in case that's helpful).

He gives an example of a class that contains two strings as member variables (it's a "Person" class with two strings as the first and last name of the person).  He states about this class that it doesn't contain dynamic members.  Instead it contains objects that have dynamic members.

Fine.  What exactly then is a *dynamic member*?  Is it sufficient for me to understand it as a member that must be instantiated with new in the constructor and, therefore, destroyed with delete?

Comment: I think he just means that those members are instantiated using `new` in ctor and `delete` in ~ctor, exactly as you said

Comment: Remember that if you're using `new`, you should probably also be using a smart pointer.